# Is it possible to create a new datatype in postgresql as a range of values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table

What I want to do is declare a new type that is a range on numbers, something along the lines of:

```
CREATE TYPE mynumbers AS ENUM(generate_series(1,144,0.5));
```

Essentially I want to have a type mynumbers that will be the values between 1 to 144 in step increments of 0.5

Comment: You can use a check constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a domain:

```
CREATE DOMAIN mynumbers AS numeric
   CHECK (VALUE >= 1 AND VALUE <= 144
          AND trunc(VALUE * 2) = VALUE * 2);
```

Such a domain can be used like a data type in column definitions.